# What documentation is needed to bring a dog on a flight from Denmark to Norway on Scandinavian Airlines?

Tags: pets

I'm planning to travel with my dog first (1) from the US to Denmark, and then, a few days later, (2) from Copenhagen to Norway on Scandinavian airlines.

What documentation will Scandinavian airlines want to see in order for me to bring my dog on the flight from Denmark to Norway?

Comment: Have you asked SAS directly?

Comment: I spent 36 minutes on hold and was then able to add my in-cabin pet to the booking. However, the representative didn't understand my question when I asked what paperwork would be required. :-/